# Union type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Why this defination of type is not allowed in TypeScript?

```
type profileType = 'TEACHER' | 'PRINCIPAL';

interface FormList {
    [ key: profileType ] : IForm[];
}

let forms: FormList;

forms = {
    'TEACHER' : [{ id: 1, name: "o" }, { id: 1, name: "b" }]
}
```

It invokes an error in line: `[ key: profileType ] : IForm[];`.

Comment: There is no need for in this case it since, you can simply define an interface as in your previous question.

Comment: I need to be ensure in allowed keys, so therefore I try to make this key strict

Comment: Your `[key: ...]` can be of type number or string, nothing else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map string literals from union into new type. This is called [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) in typescript:

```
type IForm = {};
type ProfileType = 'TEACHER' | 'PRINCIPAL';    

type FormList = { [P in ProfileType]: IForm[] };

let forms: FormList;

forms = {
    'TEACHER': [{ id: 1, name: "o" }, { id: 1, name: "b" }],
    'PRINCIPAL': [{ id: 1, name: "o" }, { id: 1, name: "b" }]
}
```