# Loosely typed object with union type key in typescript

Tags: typescript, interface, typescript-typings

I'm trying to create an interface of loosely typed objects with unions type key.

```
export type ObjectsType = 'text' | 'image' | 'circleText';

export interface IAllowedObjects {
    [key: ObjectsType] : boolean;
}
```

but getting

> An index signature parameter type cannot be a union type. Consider
>   using a mapped object type instead

already tried some solutions but no luck.

1. tried [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51062671/union-type-in-typescript) solution

```
    export type ObjectsType = 'text' | 'image' | 'circleText';
    export interface IAllowedObjects {
         [key in ObjectsType] : boolean;
    }
```

> A computed property name in an interface must refer to an expression
>   whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol'
>
> A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol',
>   or 'any'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) only with [type aliases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases), interfaces cannot do this.

```
export type ObjectsType = 'text' | 'image' | 'circleText';
export type IAllowedObjects =  {
  [key in ObjectsType]: boolean;
}
```

[Code sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=4&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDyAjAVsAxjAZwBVlUBeOAchlBkrgB8qBLAWwEMBzYepy3ZlFwAbYEVqUA3AChQkWAlJwAkgEFhwiAHdgAE0w58BOBTgBvaXDgBtANbBEcZgDt02PIRIoAugC44GBAQouzOMgC%20QA)

Comment: Thanks, solution works, I was exporting interface instead of type.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the [Record](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt) utility type which does the same as fords answer

```
type ObjectsType = 'text' | 'image' | 'circleText'
type IAllowedObjects = Record<ObjectsType, boolean>
```